# React Typescript: Cannot add inferred document in Firestore Database

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a document I inferred into the Firestore database

I have tried assigning `DocumentData` to the object but I think I am doing things wrong. Here is my file `App.tsx`:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import TodoList from "./Components/TodoList"
import { RootState } from "./todoStore"
import { createTodoCard } from "./todoReducer"
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics"
import { collection, addDoc, getFirestore, DocumentData } from "firebase/firestore"

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app)

// Here is the type I inferred
interface TodoListTemplate {
  id: number,
}

const App: FC = () => {
  // Contains all the generated todo-lists
  const [generatedTodoList, setGeneratedTodoList] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const selector = useSelector((state: RootState) => { return state.todo });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  async function generateTodoList(): Promise<void> {
    const todoList: TodoListTemplate = await addDoc(collection(db, 'todoListCard'), {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    } as DocumentData) // This does not work //
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(createTodoCard(generatedTodoList));
    console.log(selector.todoCard)
  }, [generatedTodoList])

  return (
    ... Do stuff ...
  )
}

export default App
```

Instead of adding the document, I get an error like this:

```
Type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 'TodoListTemplate'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Thank you for your responses in advanced :)

Comment: can you try this solution in this github [thread](https://github.com/invertase/react-query-firebase/issues/38#issuecomment-1115082533) which might help

Comment: from what I can see in the thread, they seem to be querying someting from the database, which is the exact opposite of what i am trying to do but i tried it anyways. it still does not work and shows this error: 
Type 'DocumentReference<{ id: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'TodoListTemplate'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.